# asp.net Outlook creates 2 emails instead of 1

Tags: c#, asp.net, email, webforms, outlook

I use Asp.net WebForm 
I have a problem with Outlook Application. When user wants to submit a report/order from the Browser by email in Outlook it creates 2 emails instead of one. I literally don't understand what may be a problem.

Here is a part that is responsible for creating and sending email:

```
//Send email
try
{
    Outlook.Application outlookApp = new Outlook.Application();
    Outlook.MailItem mailItem = (Outlook.MailItem)outlookApp.CreateItem(Outlook.OlItemType.olMailItem);
    MailAddress to = new MailAddress(email_primary);
    MailAddress cc = new MailAddress(email_cc);
    mailItem.To = to.ToString();
    mailItem.CC = cc.ToString();

    mailItem.Subject = "MB Accessories Order";

    mailItem.Importance = Outlook.OlImportance.olImportanceNormal;
    mailItem.BodyFormat = Outlook.OlBodyFormat.olFormatHTML;
    mailItem.Body = "Dear Colleagues, Please find below my MB Accessories & Collection enquiry for MBCME price (VAT included) and availability. FullName:" + Fullname_converted + " Items:" + joinedData + "";
    mailItem.Display(false);
    //mailItem.Send();
    Response.Write("E-mail sent!");
}
catch (Exception eX)
{
    throw new Exception("cDocument: Error occurred trying to Create an Outlook Email" + Environment.NewLine + eX.Message);
}
```

If you need more information, just let me know.

Comment: double click triggers the function twice? did you debug? is it hit twice?

Comment: In general, trying to automate the Office applications from a web application *is unsupported* and tends to have all kind of nice side-effects. This could very well be one of them.

Comment: To send an email from an ASP.Net WebForms application, either take the manual route and build it using SmtpClient (or something more modern) or send it through an external service like SendGrid.

Comment: @Paul-Jan I wanted to use Smtp, but i don't use it because this web application we use only in our intranet.  :)

Answer (score 1):

I solved this problem by implementing  instead of html button
instead of:

```
<button id="idbutton" runat="server" onserverclick="btn_submit_Click">Submit</button>
```

i used

```
<asp:Button runat="server" Text="Submit" OnClick="btn_submit_Click" />
```

and now it works fine

Comment: Ah, good find! Too bad you didn't share that part of the code. Probably a duplicate of. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1562580/htmlbutton-handler-fires-twice-when-clicked-when-autoeventwireup-true , but when you are doing classic asp.net webforms and there is no specific reason to choose otherwise using asp:button is best practice anyway.

Comment: It works fine on your dev machine. In production, it will attempt to run the script on the server with no user to see the newly created message..

Comment: @DmitryStreblechenko Hi Dmitry, you were right, my code doesn't work on the server. I have an error "Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {0006F03A-0000-0000-C000-000000000046} failed due to the following error: 80040154 Class not registered (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80040154 (REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG)). "

Comment: @DmitryStreblechenko I can't find solution to this, how can i use outlook in the server?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot run that code on the server. Your options are

1. JS on the client side - has to be IE, and the site must be trusted to be able to create COM objects.
2. Create an EML (MIME) message on the server side and let the user download it - Outlook will be happy to open and display it. To make sure the message is in the unsent state, set `X-Unsent` MIME header to 1.